# JavaScript element.prepend vs element.insertAdjacentElement

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Modern browsers implement the following useful methods:

- `.prepend()`
- `.append()`
- `.before()`
- `.after()`

which are a welcome addition.

They also implement `.insertAdjacentElement()`, which as far as I can tell, will achieve the same results, albeit a little more verbose.

Apart from syntax, is there a practical difference between the newer methods and the (slightly) older `.insertAdjacentElement()`?

I am aware that the newer methods are not yet available in Microsoft Browsers, but `.insertAdjacentElement()` is available even in IE8, so a polyfill shouldn’t be hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no significant difference other than syntax.

The new methods can take multiple arguments, where each argument can be either a node or a string. `insertAdjacentElement` takes a position (string) and a node. If you want to insert multiple nodes, you'll have to invoke it multiple times. If you want to insert text, you have to use `insertAdjacentText` instead.

The spec is the best source I could find:

- https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-prepend
- https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-insertadjacentelement

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is my take on a polyfill: https://jsfiddle.net/thewebcoder/j49t9t9h/